# Multiple WCF service endpoints in IIS breaks wcftestclient

Tags: wcf, iis, web-config, nettcpbinding

I'm trying to expose a WCF service through both http and net.tcp binding in IIS.
Everything seems to work as expected when I specify just the net.tcp bindings, or just the http bindings, but when I add both the wcftestclient program and all other service proxy generators fail:

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from net.tcp://host/application/service.svc 
>   ...
>   Metadata Exchange Error    URI: net.tcp://host/application/service.svc   Metadata contains a  reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://host/application/service.svc '.    There was > no endpoint listening at net.tcp://host/application/service.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

My web.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>      
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="MyServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="mex-http"      binding="mexHttpBinding"   name="mex-http" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint address="service-http"  binding="basicHttpBinding" name="db-http"  contract="IMyService" />
        <endpoint address="mex-tcp"       binding="mexTcpBinding"    name="mex-http" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint address="service-tcp"   binding="netTcpBinding"    name="db-http"  contract="IMyService" />
      </service>      
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

So, if I remove the mex-http and db-http endpoints, everything is fine. If I don't, the service is accessible over http but not over tcp. If I remove the tcp endpoints, of course the http one is still available. Any thoughts?

**Edit:**
Based on Marc's suggestion, I changed the relevant `net.tcp` endpoints to read

```
<endpoint name="mex-http" address="net.tcp://localhost/myservice/MyService.svc/mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
<endpoint name="db-http"  address="net.tcp://localhost/myservice/MyService.svc"     binding="netTcpBinding" contract="IMyService" />
```

which works as expected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out

- [How to: Host a WCF Service in WAS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733109.aspx), and
- [How to: Install and Configure WCF Activation Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731053.aspx)

Have you completed those steps to make `net.tcp` available in IIS / WAS?

Assuming you have - I believe hosting a `net.tcp` WCF service in WAS requires you to either define a `net.tcp` base address and/or complete addresses on the `net.tcp` endpoints - since those things are not defined by the IIS virtual directory.

So try:

```
<services>      
   <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="MyServiceBehavior">
       ...(your http stuff here)....
       <endpoint name="mex-http" 
           address="net.tcp://YourServer:7171/NetTcpService/mex"       
           binding="mexTcpBinding"    
           contract="IMetadataExchange" />
       <endpoint name="db-http"  
           address="net.tcp://YourServer:7171/NetTcpService/MyService"       
           binding="netTcpBinding"    
           contract="IMyService" />
  </service>      
</services>
```

or:

```
<services>      
   <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="MyServiceBehavior">
      <host>
         <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://YourServer:7171/NetTcpService"/>
         </baseAddresses>
       </host>
       ...(your http stuff here)....
       <endpoint name="mex-http" 
           address="mex"
           binding="mexTcpBinding"    
           contract="IMetadataExchange" />
       <endpoint name="db-http"  
           address="MyService"
           binding="netTcpBinding"    
           contract="IMyService" />
  </service>      
</services>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, `net.tcp` is available (without the basicHttpBinding it actually works). I believe the `<host>` addition in web.config is ignored when hosting in IIS, and sadly the suggestion to specify a full endpoint address seems to make no difference at all.

Comment: You're actually right, IIS needs the net.tcp endpoint address to be fully specified. It should point to the corresponding `.svc` though!

Comment: @FrankRazenberg: OK; thanks for the heads-up. I've never hosted net.tcp inside IIS/WAS myself, so that's something to remember for the future - thanks!